# Types of electrostatic force

Tags: electrostatics

In some references, electrostatic force is said to have 3 types: Coulombic force, image force, and gradient force. I really would feel grateful if anybody can explain to me the difference between them, because I really can't find any good reference detailing about them.

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. Really you need to go off and Google those subjects then come back to us with any specific questions.